# Como faço para que o firebase realtime databese entenda que isso > 29.90 < é uma String e não um número?

Tags: firebase

Olá a todos estou desenvolvendo um app que no qual usa o firebase realtime database.

O meu problema é que eu estou tentanto o valor de 29.90 em uma da minha database.

Ex:

Valor do produto: 29.90

Eu quero pegar esse valor dentro do meu programa interno.

> String valor = datasnapshot.chil("Valor do produto").getValue(String.class);

Porém, o meu programa fecha.

Eu tentei passar o valor no firebase das seguintes formas: 29.90 e "29.90" mas nenhuma funcionou.

Será que o problema é o "."?

Answer (score 2):

Então se você está colocando exatamente essa linha de codigo, o problema pode ser o "d" faltando em "child", então deveria ser:

`String valor = datasnapshot.child("Valor do produto").getValue();`

Comment: Obrigado amigo mas eu resolvi o problema...... O erro estava em outra variável no firebase realtime.

Comment: Ex: eu tinha no realtime data base uma string que armazenava um endereço de uma imagem na internet, mas eu não percebi que estava vazia. O problema era que eu estava usando a biblioteca Picasso.

Comment: Eu pegava o valor do firebase e armazenava numa String interna e passava para a biblioteca picasso. Picasso.get().load(" ").inTo(imageView); > Dá erro se passar o load vazio